# PHP how to print the amount of characters from a string in a bar chart/graph?

Tags: php, css, string, function, loops

I want to show the amount of characters from a string in a bar chart/graph in PHP. I have this function:

```
function characterCount($amount) {
    $a = substr_count($amount, 'a');
    $b = substr_count($amount, 'b');
    return $a;
    return $b;
}

echo characterCount("abbaabbaaa");
```

How can I print the result in a bar chart/graph?

Tnx!

Comment: You would have to google "PHP bar chart."  I recommend using [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery)

Comment: Use CSS to create a Div with a color.  Have the height sized with the result of your calculation.  The higher the number, the higher the bar.

Comment: `<div style="background: red; width: <?php echo strlen($a) * 10 ?>px">&nbsp;</div>`. Plus... two return statements? That's not going to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do like this

```
<style>
 .showbar {
    width: 8px;
    margin: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
</style>

<?php

function characterCount($amount)
{
    $a = substr_count($amount, 'a');
    $b = substr_count($amount, 'b');

   return array($a,$b);

}

$r=characterCount('aaab');
echo $r[0].'<div style="height: '.$r[0].'em;" class="showbar"></div>'.$r[1].'<div style="height: '.$r[1].'em;" class="showbar"></div>';
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your code is already off to a bad start because you don't seem to understand how `return` works.

That aside, there is already a function [`count_chars`](http://php.net/count-chars) built-in that does what you want.

As for presenting it in a chart, the simplest way would be to do a quick Google search for some graphing plugins. Personally, I'd use HTML, a set of `<div>`s side-by-side with their `height` set to the relative frequency, but really there's just too many ways to list. Go and give it a try, and if you're having more problems then come back with a more specific question :)

For now, though, I hope the `count_chars` function gets you on the right path.